# Textarea in chat/disussion area should be more user friendly

Tags: feature-request, chat, user-experience

I noticed that the textarea is not very user friendly, since you cant scroll:
If you have too many lines, then you cant read them anymore.

[image]

Comment: The text box on stackoverflow is gray instead of orange -- this seems to be from one of the other sites of the network. Maybe it would be more appropriate to ask this on meta.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Chat is network wide feature. Maybe better ask on Meta. SE. But frankly, seems like a small thing. Very long chat messages seem to be an anti-feature.

Comment: @yivi correct. It's a chat, not a "share my life story in one text blob" :) I'd still consider the lack of scrollbar a styling bug though... One I can't replicate, I get a scrollbar.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It is the new Orange mode, for those who hate Dark mode and the default. Probably A/B testing ....

Comment: You can post a book in one chat message: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297928 ....

Comment: @rene I can't help but notice the scrollbar there...

Comment: @Nick blame Chrome. I know nothing.

Comment: /shrug, I get one in firefox as well

Comment: @Nick Are you Brave enough to test in IE6?

Comment: @rene No need, it's not in the list of supported browsers :p

Comment: @rene No unicorn-rainbow-colour theme? I'm disappointed!

Comment: @rene However given the recent purchase by a Dutch company, orange theme would make sense :) Maybe only for people with Dutch IP, so I'll have to suffer the boring gray...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz only people who are into soccer actually (pretend to) like the color orange.

Comment: The color is different because I chatted on https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Gimby And [Max Verstappen's fans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4p7k.png)...

Comment: @Gimby, "It's a chat, not a "share my life story in one text blob""
Sometimes you need to post some lines of code

Comment: @Gimby So all of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Amsterdam%27s_Canals.jpg are into soccer? That's frightening ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text area in chat *is* scrollable, both with the scrollbar it shows and with a mouse scroll wheel:

[image: Scrollable text area]

Just don't use the resizing handle to resize it beyond the bottom of the page, it's better for resizing the width and less useful for the height.

Comment: I was discussion with someone on https://magento.stackexchange.com/ maybe it is different there. I thought it is same for each site. I used that resizing handle, maybe it was caused by it.

Comment: @Black The resizing handle is high risk, low reward, I'd just avoid it :)

Comment: Coincidentally, long chat messages are also high risk, low reward.